# Is it possible to run Spring Boot as API and Wordpress as Frontend CMS in a single domain

Tags: wordpress, spring-boot

Currently, I am working on a project which designed to make Spring Boot as Backend and Wordpress as Frontend.
The integration between both side is via API. However, I realize that my Spring Boot and Wordpress must be both running to make the connection workable.
I am new to this, so I have no idea whether I could include my spring boot as a subdomain inside my wordpress domain or other alternative?

Does anyone experiences can share me about how to host and run both program inside a single domain.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best idea is use sub domain for backend service: api.domain.com

Or you can use rewrite rule of web server to redirect request